# Adding a second pager to a Jquery Cycle slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, jquery-cycle, pager

I am trying to add a second pager to my slideshows in 1/3 > format so if there are 3 slides it shows how many slides and what slide your on and if you want to move forward you just click the arrow. It has to be simple but I can't find any examples out there. Here is what I have so far:

```
$(function() {
$('.slideshow').each(function() {
    var $nav = $('<div class="nav"></div>').insertAfter(this);
    var $nav2 = $('<div class="nav2"></div>').insertBefore(this);
    $('<div class="caption">&nbsp;</div>').insertAfter($nav);

    $(this).cycle({
        fx:     'fade',
        speed:   300,
        timeout: 0,
        pager:   $nav,
        after:   onAfter
    });
});

function onAfter(curr, next, opts) {
    var src = '&nbsp;';
    if (next.src)
        src = next.src.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+$)/)[1];
    $(curr).parent().nextAll('div.caption:first').html(src);
}
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks, Jeff Lamb...I tried that and its almost there. Because I have 2 slideshows on one page the navs are superimposing on one another so if I go forward on one both of the captions change. I tried just  changing class names but it still superimposes. What am I missing here? Here is my updated code:

```
$(function() {
$('.slideshow').each(function() {
    var $nav = $('<div class="nav"></div>').insertAfter(this);
    var $nav2 = $('<div class="nav2"></div>').insertBefore(this);

    $('<div class="caption">&nbsp;</div>').insertBefore($nav);
    $('<div class="caption2">&nbsp;</div>').insertAfter($nav2);

    $('.next').click(function() {
        $('.slideshow').cycle('next');
    });
    $('.next2').click(function() {
        $('.two').cycle('next');
    });

    $(this).cycle({
        fx:     'fade',
        speed:   300,
        timeout: 0,
        pager:   $nav,
        after:   onAfter
    });
});

function onAfter() { 
    $('.caption').html('<h3>' + (parseInt($(this).index())+1) + ' / ' + $(".slideshow div").length + '</h3>');
}
function onAfter() { 
    $('.caption2').html('<h3>' + (parseInt($(this).index())+1) + ' / ' + $(".two div").length + '</h3>');
}
```

I do want the option of adding a 3rd slideshow if needed. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
<h2>CASE STUDIES</h2>
<input type="button" class="next" value=">" />

<div class="slideshow">
<div> <img src="images/jorge-pensi.png" width="278" height="270" />
  <h1>Jorge<br/>
    <strong>Pensi</strong></h1>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
  <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
 </div>
  <div> <img src="images/jorge-pensi.png" width="278" height="270" />
  <h1>Designer<br/>
    <strong>Two</strong></h1>
   <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
  <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="slideshow-container">
 <h2>OUR DESIGNERS</h2>
 <input type="button" class="next2" value=">" />

  <div class="slideshow two">
  <div> <img src="images/jorge-pensi.png" width="278" height="270" />
  <h1>Jorge<br/>
    <strong>Pensi</strong></h1>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
  <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
</div>
<div> <img src="images/jorge-pensi.png" width="278" height="270" />
  <h1>Designer<br/>
    <strong>Two</strong></h1>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
  <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Regarding the update: You're calling the same 'onAfter' function for both slideshows.  Unless you want to make this extendable to more than 2 slideshows, don't do the .each() and just configure each slideshow independently.  Also, it's difficult figuring out what you're getting at since you're not including the html.

Comment: You should ask the entire question next time.  That way those who answer won't need to rewrite their code...

Comment: You are right. I do apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's a rewrite.  It doesn't add the html captions and buttons in js, but you can change that if you like.  You can make it automatically increment via the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $('.ss').each(function() {
        i+=1;

        $('#prev'+i).click(function() {
            $('#slideshow'+i).cycle('prev');
        });
    }
}
```

However, I feel like I'm writing the entire thing for you instead of you writing the page yourself.  Here's a working version that calls each slideshow out explictly:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    startShow1();

    $('#prev1').click(function() {
        $('#slideshow1').cycle('prev');
    });
    $('#next1').click(function() {
        $('#slideshow1').cycle('next');
    });


    startShow2();

    $('#prev2').click(function() {
        $('#slideshow2').cycle('prev');
    });
    $('#next2').click(function() {
        $('#slideshow2').cycle('next');
    });
});

function startShow1() {
    $('#slideshow1').cycle({
        fx:       'fade', 
        speed:    0,
        timeout:  600,
        autostop: 1,
        after:    onAfter1
    });
}

function startShow2() {
    $('#slideshow2').cycle({
        fx:       'fade', 
        speed:    0,
        timeout:  600,
        autostop: 1,
        after:    onAfter2
    });
}


function onAfter1() { 
    $('#caption1').html('<h3>' + (parseInt($(this).index())+1) + ' / ' + $("#slideshow1 img").length + '</h3>'); 
}

function onAfter2() { 
    $('#caption2').html('<h3>' + (parseInt($(this).index())+1) + ' / ' + $("#slideshow2 img").length + '</h3>'); 
}

</script> 
</head> 
<table>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <div class='ssc' id="ss1_container">
            <div class='ss' id="slideshow1">
                <img src="img1.png">
                <img src="img2.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="50px">
            <div id="caption1">

            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" id="prev1" value="Prev" />
            <input type="button" id="next1" value="Next" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <div class='ssc' id="ss2_container">
            <div class='ss' id="slideshow2">
                <img src="img1.png">
                <img src="img2.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="50px">
            <div id="caption2">

            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" id="prev2" value="Prev" />
            <input type="button" id="next2" value="Next" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Jeff. This is perfect and makes complete sense. Thanks so much. I had worked on it for so long and was stumped. This is more than enough. If there was a way to pay you though here I would. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if cycle's API supports this specifically.  This will work, though.

```
<div id="ss">
    <img src="image.png">
    <img src="image.png">
    <img src="image.png">
    <img src="image.png">
    <img src="image.png">
</div>
```

Specify `after` in the slideshow

```
$('#ss').cycle({
    after:    onAfter
});
```

Define onAfter:

```
function onAfter() { 
    $('#caption').html('<h3>' + (parseInt($(this).index())+1) + ' / ' + $("#slideshow3 img").length + '</h3>');
}
```

Define a div under your images:

```
<div id="caption"></div>
```

Add buttons and/or arrows:

```
<input type="button" id="prev" value="<" />
<input type="button" id="next" value=">" />
```

in your $(document).ready function, assign click actions to your buttons:

```
$('#prev').click(function() {
    $('#ss').cycle('prev');
});
$('#next').click(function() {
    $('#ss').cycle('next');
});
```